# Show "Microsoft Active Directory" information table in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a spreadsheet in Microsoft Active Directory
Now I want to display the information in this table in WordPress
I came across [this plugin](https://fa.wordpress.org/plugins/next-active-directory-integration/) according to the searches I did
But this plugin also does not have the ability to display information registered in Active Directory
What method or plugin do you think I should use to display Active Directory registered information in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) to display user informatiom. [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php) is a good starting point.For example:

```
public function loadViewData()
{
$viewData = [];

// Check for flash errors
if (session('error')) {
    $viewData['error'] = session('error');
    $viewData['errorDetail'] = session('errorDetail');
}

// Check for logged on user
if (session('userName'))
{
    $viewData['userName'] = session('userName');
    $viewData['userEmail'] = session('userEmail');
    $viewData['userTimeZone'] = session('userTimeZone');
}

return $viewData;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Best,
James